# How do I change the name of a docker ror app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker

I’m following the [docker ruby quickstart](https://docs.docker.com/compose/rails/) tutorial and I’d like to change the default app name “myapp” to something else, say “mycoolapp.” To do so, I’ve replaced every reference myapp with mycoolapp, yet, when I try to run setup, I get the error:

```
Successfully built 4abc3c1c15bd
Successfully tagged docker_ruby_quickstart_web:latest
cp: config/database.yml: No such file or directory
Starting docker_ruby_quickstart_db_1 ... done
rake aborted!
No Rakefile found (looking for: rakefile, Rakefile, rakefile.rb, Rakefile.rb)
/usr/local/bundle/gems/rake-13.0.1/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

This error does not make sense to me, as the setup script for the myapp version and the mycoolapp version are identical. **What am I missing here?**

Images of Diffs:
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
To reproduce, check out the [replace-app-name-with-mycoolapp branch in my repo](https://github.com/ericadohring/docker_ruby_quickstart/tree/replace-app-name-with-mycoolapp)

- The 2nd commit has the vanilla "myapp" version, which sets up without error and shows you hello rails on localhost:3000 after docker-compose up.
- The 3rd commit has the "mycoolapp" version, which displays the error I pasted above upon setup.

I also did a docker-clean run between runs just to ensure nothing weird was happening with danging images.

Comment: Can you please add the relevant information such as the change list to the question body itself? Readers should not have to dig through your repo to find it and this prevents the prevailing link rot that makes most forums useless over time.

Comment: Do you mean paste this into the body of the question? https://github.com/ericadohring/docker_ruby_quickstart/commit/e7bcef4526f11e535444a31a56b1cc96235733e0

Comment: Yes exactly. Questions should be self-contained as far as possible.

Comment: Added images of the diffs (pasting it as code didn't look correctly formatted)

Comment: You can use the command-line `diff` or `git show` commands to get textual diffs.  Please do not paste images of code into SO questions.

Comment: The diff in and of itself is not a [mcve] especially since its likely that the problem is something you haven’t changed.  Better still would be to include enough actual code (the `Dockerfile` and `docker-compose.yml` files at least) to reproduce the problem.  Otherwise this question is asking people to make guesses about the code you haven’t shown.